# Storing an extended object in the httpSession

Tags: java, session, tomcat, servlets

In the code below learning is an Learning instance which I want to save as is to the http session

```
learning = new Learning(learningContext);
HttpSession webSession = request.getSession();
webSession.setAttribute("learning", learning);
Learning learnTest = webSession.getAttribute("learning");
```

When I run the code below I get:

```
Incompatible types
Learning learnTest = webSession.getAttribute("learning")      
required: Learning
found:    Object
```

Can I save a non generic object to the session? Is there another way to achieve this?

Comment: Have you tried any workarounds like .toString() or casting?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to cast the object like this -

```
Learning learnTest = (Learning) webSession.getAttribute("learning")
```

You need to cast to a specific type as return type of getAttribute is Object.

Answer (score 1):

The javadoc for `HttpSession.getAttribute` says:

> java.lang.Object   getAttribute(java.lang.String name)
>             Returns the object bound with the specified name in this session, or null if no object is bound under the name.

I means that *by construction* it will always return a mere object. As you know (or hope) that you have put a `Learning` there, you just have to do an explicit cast:

```
Learning learnTest = (Learning) webSession.getAttribute("learning");
```